# Add different text to a window

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4

I have a button and a text label. Each time the button is pressed, i would like text placed from a line edit to be placed onto the window. So far I can only get one text to draw onto the window, even if I create another textlabel. Ive tried seeting a click count determining how many times a user has clicked a button but this doesnt work either. Heres what I have so far, any suggestions?

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui  import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args)
        self.centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.setGeometry(450,100,350,680)

        self.btn1 = QPushButton("Enter", self.centralWidget)
        self.btn1.setGeometry(10,50,150, 20)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.enter)

        self.edit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.edit.setGeometry(10, 10, 150, 20)

        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setGeometry(240, 170,150, 20)


    def enter(self):
        self.label.setText(self.edit.text())


def main(args):
    global app
    app = App(args)
    app.exec_()

class App(QApplication):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QApplication.__init__(self, *args)
        self.main = Window()
        self.connect(self, SIGNAL("lastWindowClosed()"), self.byebye )
        self.main.show()

    def byebye( self ):
        self.exit(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your example code, the main one being that you are trying to manually arrange the widgets, rather than using a layout.

It's hard to tell from your question exactly what you expect the output to be, so I've assumed you want the text from line-edit to be appended to the label, so that you end up with a series of lines.

Here's a simplified version of your example that hopefully does what you want:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.btn1 = QtGui.QPushButton("Enter", self)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.enter)
        self.edit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setAlignment(
            QtCore.Qt.AlignTop | QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn1)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    def enter(self):
        text = self.edit.text()
        if text:
            self.label.setText('%s\n%s' % (self.label.text(), text))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(450, 100, 350, 680)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Everytime the user clicks the button for an input, i want that text to to outputted onto a different label

Comment: @Pro-grammer. Adding a new label would give identical output to my answer. What are you actually trying to achieve? Why do you need separate labels? What should happen if the number of labels grows beyond the size of the window?